# Get a randomized aberrancy around given value

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, math

I would like to add a kind of ripple to an array of known values of type **double**. I point that out because Random.Next / Random.NextDouble() behave different.

How do i best achieve this task?

Let say i have 20 values in the array, 
`List<double> arr = new List<double>() { 40, 40, 40, 40 ..... };`
20 values which are averaged on amount 40, with a total of 800, to make it easier.

After this method, I would like the *overall total* still remain 800, but each individual value should ben modified. The values should be positive, because they are `total+=i` added afterwards.

So far this problem are solved using a percentage of the given quantity of values. 
`1.0 / 20 = 0.05, then multiplicate that with the total and  the iteration number. Then subtract the result from the remainder. Finally i just return a sort by new Guid()`.

As you already see, this method was only a little terrific, while there was just about 5-20 values. In my case today, this array need to stand 500-2000 values (0,2-0,05% each value).

Instead I would like to have a derivative or such, that make a distortion with +-x% of value 40 as base. Or, perhaps even better, +-x% on whatever single value in the array).

**[UPDATE]**

I will add the question with an update based on the replies on this question.

```
    Random rnd = new Random();
    List<double> ripple = new List<double>();

    int qty = bArray.Count();
    double diff = last.Value - first.Value;

    if (qty == 1)
    {
        double linearAvg = (diff / qty) / 2;
        ripple.Add(linearAvg);
    }
    else
    {
        double[] rndarr = new double[qty];

        for (int i = 0; i < qty; i++)
            rndarr[i] = rnd.NextDouble();

        double rndArrSum = rndarr.Sum();

        for (int i = 0; i < qty; i++)
            rndarr[i] /= rndArrSum; 

        for (int i = 0; i < qty; i++)
            ripple.Add(diff * rndarr[i]);
    }

    double valueOverall = first.Value;
    for (int i = (qty > 1) ? 1 : 0; i < qty; i++)
        valueOverall += ripple[i];
```

Allowance has been made for the last generated value not to overlap. In addition, an exception when the list contains only two values​​. The `qty=1` may look magic, but it refers to how the object bArray looks like in real. I think the whole idea is clear anyway.

Comment: Can you randomly perturb just the first n-1 values, then make the last value the needed value to make the total come out to 800?

Comment: @mellamokb that sounds like it would disproportionately skew the last value.

Comment: @Dr.Wily'sApprentice: Indeed it does, I tested it :)  Another idea: perturb all the values, then spread out the amount it is off among all the numbers.

Comment: I was into the idea of control the set of percentages (divide by x amount and such) but halted on a feeling i was begun finding moon through Mars.. :)

Comment: Sorting with a guid as the key for randomization is a worst practice. **Guids are guaranteed to be unique, not guaranteed to be random**. A guid generator is perfectly within its rights to generate sequential guids, and some do! If you want to sort by a random number then **generate a random number**. Use the right tool for the job; only generate a guid when you want a *unique identifier*.

Comment: Eric, you are completely correct about that. Thanks for point it out, at least to the fact Im not "yet" hunted because of it's presence in this question :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way you could do this is to generate N random numbers between 0 and 1 (exclusive). Sum them. Then divide each number by the sum. You now have a list of N random numbers that sum to 1. Now, multiply each of those numbers by your desired sum to get the numbers that will go into your final array.

If you want your values to be +/- some percentage, then use `Random.Next` to generate the random numbers within some range and sum them. Then divide by the total to get the list of numbers that sums to 1. The final step is the same.

Comment: Aha! Of crz, thanks! Obvious.. now when you say it :). It will automagically also solve second approach. I try it out in a few hours.

Comment: Updated with a part of the solution,

Answer (score 2):

Another method would be to loop through the array and perturb by percentage value.  Once complete, calculate how far off the total is, and add the overage amount spread equally throughout all the numbers.  Here's some sample code:

```
var test = Enumerable.Repeat<double>(40, 100).ToArray();
var percent = 0.5d;

var rand = new Random();
var expectedTotal = test.Sum();
var currentTotal = 0d;
var numCount = test.Count();

for (var i = 0; i < numCount; i++)
{
    var num = test[i];
    var range = num * percent * 2;

    var newNum = num + (rand.NextDouble() - 0.5) * (range);
    currentTotal += newNum;
    test[i] = newNum;
}

var overage = (expectedTotal - currentTotal);

for (var i = 0; i < numCount; i++)
    test[i] += overage / numCount;
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is my solution.

Basically, it "jitters" each value by some specified percentage, and then checks the difference between the original total and the "jittered" total.  In order to make the final total match the original total, it adds a flat amount to each "jittered" value.

I feel like this is not a great solution from a mathematical perspective, because I think that adding the flat amount to each value will probably distort the true percentage of abberation for each value.  There is probably a more mathematically correct way to apply the remainder across the set of values in such a way as to preserve the intended percentage of abberation, but I imagine that doing so would require several passes, whereas this solution completes in a set number of passes.

```
// prepare data
double[] values = new double[20];
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    values[i] = 40.0;
}

// get the original total
double originalTotal = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    originalTotal += values[i];
}

// specify an abberation percentage
double x = 0.05;

// jitter each value +/- the abberation percentage
// also capture the total of the jittered values
Random rng = new Random();
double intermediateTotal = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    values[i] += values[i] * (rng.NextDouble() - 0.5) * (2.0 * x);
    intermediateTotal += values[i];
}

// calculate the difference between the original total and the current total
double remainder = originalTotal - intermediateTotal;

// add a flat amount to each value to make the totals match
double offset = remainder / values.Length;
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    values[i] += offset;
}

// calculate the final total to verify that it matches the original total
double finalTotal = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    finalTotal += values[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Choose a random number (symmetric about zero) for each step *between* successive numbers.  Then, add it to the first, and subtract it from the second:

```
for(int i=1; i<length; i++) {
  dx = (rng.NextDouble() - 0.5) * scale;
  arr[i-1] += dx;
  arr[i] -= dx;
}
```

This should ensure that the sum of the array stays the same (modulo floating point error), while the array elements are all modified.