# Generate an event X numbers of times per second but not evenly spaced within each second

Tags: c#

I'd like to write a class that will fire an event `x` a pre-defined numbers of times per second call it `n`.

However, I would like `x` **NOT** to fire evenly spaced within each second.

So, say `n` = 100, 25 might fire in the first 300ms then a further 50 over the next 600ms and the final 25 in the remaining 100ms.

Ideally, I'd like better granularity then that presented above and a greater range of spacing within each second.

I'm wondering if I would be able to create an array with defined millisecond and how many events to fire.  Then use a loop and the `Stopwatch` class to determine whether the defined events for that millisecond waypoint should be fired.

The question is, could the array be calculated for each second fast enough, each second should have random spacing.

Obviously, the event would need to be Asynchronous to avoid getting delayed by what ever is wired up to it.

Anyone come across any similar need?

### UPDATE

I thought I'd at least put my initial effort on here.

So I found that there is enough resolution to check which millisecond you are currently in and which second.  Basically, each second I rebuild my spacing each millisecond gets an entry in the array and each entry says how many times to fire the event that millisecond.

My issue is the spacing...I needs a better way to try and clump the event count, currently this jsut seems to plonk them in evenly spaced in either 0, 1 or 2.

```
public delegate void EmptyEventDelegate();
    public class RandEvent
    {
        public event EmptyEventDelegate OnEvent = delegate { };
        private bool running = false;
        Random r = new Random();

        private int eventsPS;

        public RandEvent(int eventsPS = 1)
        {
            this.eventsPS = eventsPS;
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            running = true;
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    Run();
                });
        }

        private void Run()
        {
            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            int currentSecond = 0;
            int[] eventCount = BuildEventSpacing();

            while(running)
            {
                if (currentSecond != sw.Elapsed.Seconds)
                {
                    currentSecond = sw.Elapsed.Seconds;
                    eventCount = BuildEventSpacing();
                }
                else
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i < eventCount[sw.Elapsed.Milliseconds]; i++)
                        OnEvent();

                }
            }

            sw.Stop();
        }

        private int[] BuildEventSpacing()
        {
            var array = new int[1000];

            for (int i = 0; i < eventsPS; i++)
            {
                array[r.Next(0, 999)]++;
            }

            return array;
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            running = false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I remember a similar kind of problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178299/get-a-randomized-aberrancy-around-given-value/10178487#10178487.  The basic idea is that you space all the events an "average" of (1000ms / x), but you shift them random distances away from the average.  They are somewhat evenly spaced, but still relatively random.  The linked question generates a random list that sums to a total, so if you generated a list summing to 1, you could interpret each entry as the number of `ms` to wait between events.

Comment: Have you looked at the timer class? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

Comment: You're going to have a really tough time getting any of the .NET timers to fire 100 times per second. See http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=815. If you want better resolution, you'll have to wrap one of the system timer objects. See http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=817 for one example.

Comment: +1 @JimMischel Windows is not RT there are many reasons why even with low millisecond resolution the events will be non deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

To create the array of random event times:

1. Choose a minimum time interval between events, and fill an array with all possible event times.  For example, if you choose a granularity of 1ms, then the array will have 1000 values: 0, 0.001, 0.002, ..., 0.999.
2. Each second, shuffle the array to randomize the order of the elements.
3. Use the first n elements of the array as the firing times for the event.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Timer` and in the `Tick` event do whatever needs to be done.  Additionally, use the following method (in an additional handler of the `Tick` event) to change the interval each time.  It would be best to provide the same `Random` instance is passed to the method every time rather than providing new instances.

```
private static double millisecondsPerSecond = 1000.0;
/// <summary>
/// Method used to determine how long you would wait for the event to fire next
/// </summary>
/// <param name="averageFiresPerSecond">The approximate number of times the event should occur per second.</param>
/// <param name="variance">How much variance should be allowed, as a percentage.  i.e. a variance of 0.1 would mean that 
/// the delay will be +/- 10% of the exact rate.</param>
/// <param name="generator">A randon number generator.</param>
/// <returns>The number of milliseconds to wait for the next event to fire.</returns>
public double GetNextDelay(int averageFiresPerSecond, double variance, Random generator)
{
    double randomFactor = ((generator.NextDouble() * 2) * variance);
    return (millisecondsPerSecond / averageFiresPerSecond) * randomFactor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to make a collection of TimeSpan objects initialized to be equal and have a sum of 1 second.  The exact values would be determined by your `n`.

From there, you can offset pairs or groups by whatever values you like and your total will still be one second.  For example...

```
var offset = new TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10); // 10ms offset
timeSpans[0] += offset;
timeSpans[1] -= offset;
```

In this way you can shift them around without affecting the overall sum.  If you need to make them so that more come early and fewer come late, then you could do something like...

```
timeSpans[0] -= offset;
timeSpans[1] -= offset;
timeSpans[2] += offset;
timeSpans[2] += offset;
```

This would make indexes 0 and 1 have a shorter delay and index 2's delay will be twice as long, but keep the sum total unaffected.

The only thing to keep in mind is that none of the time spans should be less than 0s and your sum total should always be 1s, then you're golden.  Once you have your TimeSpan objects distributed, you can use them in order to pause between firing event `x`.  You're going to want to vary (randomize?) your offset a few times and each time you change it, choose new timeSpans (randomly?) to apply the offset to.  At the end of the process, it should be pretty chaotically spaced out.

I can provide a more detailed code sample if this is too abstract. :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Or you can use `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10)`. And, as I pointed out, it's unlikely that the .NET timers will give you 10 ms resolution.

Comment: The spacing is what's getting me at the moment.  As @JimMischel has mentioned I am running one of my core's at 80%.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want 100 numbers whose sum is 1. You can do the following:

1. Generate 100 random numbers between 0 and 1 (i.e. `Random.NextDouble`) and store in a list.
2. Sum the numbers.
3. Divide each number in the list by the sum.

You now have a list of 100 numbers that sum to 1.0.

Now, create a one-shot timer whose interval is the first value in the list. When it fires, the handler does its job and then sets up the one-shot timer again with an interval equal to the next value in the list.

Except that's not going to work perfectly because it doesn't take into account the amount of time required to process the tick and setup the timer again. So you'll have to keep track of that latency and adjust the next tick accordingly. But even that's not going to be perfect.

As I said in my comment, you're going to have a difficult time getting any of the .NET timers to give you more than 60 ticks per second. *At best*, you can expect 15 ms between timer ticks. Even if you go with a custom timer implementation, you're going to have some trouble because timer ticks don't occur *exactly* on time. The problem gets worse, of course, as the timer interval decreases.

In any event, there's no way that you can get a Windows timer to give you better than 1 ms resolution, so you'll have to adjust the method I described above to give you numbers that are greater than or equal to 0.001.

Your idea of using a `Stopwatch` can work with my method of creating the event intervals. Understand, however, that the loop is going to consume close to 100% of CPU time on a single core. Even then, it might not give you events *exactly* on time, because other higher-priority tasks might cause your loop to be swapped out.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace TestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class Test
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestSteps()
        {   
            var random = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
            {
                int numberOfEvents = random.Next(1,1000);
                var generator = new RandomTimeStepGenerator(numberOfEvents);
                var stopwatch = new Stopwatch(); 
                stopwatch.Start();
                var steps = generator.MillisecondDeltas;
                Assert.AreEqual(numberOfEvents, steps.Count);
                var sum = generator.MillisecondDeltas.Sum();
                Assert.AreEqual(1000.0,sum,0.1);
                Assert.IsTrue(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds<10);
            }

        }        
    }

    public class RandomTimeStepGenerator
    {
        private readonly int _numberOfEvents;
        const int timeResolution = 10000;

        public RandomTimeStepGenerator(int numberOfEvents)
        {
            _numberOfEvents = numberOfEvents;
        }

        public int NumberOfEvents
        {
            get { return _numberOfEvents; }
        }

        public List<double> MillisecondDeltas
        {
            get
            {
                var last=0;
                var result = new List<double>();
                var random = new Random();

                for (var i = 0; i < timeResolution && result.Count < _numberOfEvents; i++)
                {
                    var remainingEvents = _numberOfEvents - result.Count;
                    var remainingTime = timeResolution - i;
                    if(remainingEvents==1) // make sure the last event fires on the second
                    {
                        result.Add((timeResolution - last) / 10.0);
                        last = i;  
                    }
                    else if (remainingTime <= remainingEvents) // hurry up and fire you lazy !!! your going to run out of time 
                    {
                        result.Add(0.1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        double probability = remainingEvents / (double)remainingTime;
                        int next = random.Next(0,timeResolution);                        
                        if ((next*probability) > _numberOfEvents)
                        {
                            result.Add((i - last)/10.0);
                            last = i;
                        }
                    }                   
                }                 
                return result;
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this actually works? Does it always generate `_numberOfEvents` events? Do the intervals always sum to `timerResolution` milliseconds?

Comment: Yes that's what the tests for. :o) It always generates the number of events and it should always sum to 1000ms or 1s not **timerResolution** as that it a representation of 1/10th milliseconds. It does become unreliable if you want more than 1000 events per second. and it fails the test if you ask for 0 events as it cant sum nothing.

Comment: btw if you want `TimeSpan`'s just use `IEnumerable<TimeSpan> timeSpans = generator.MillisecondDeltas.Select(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds);`