# How to generate a random n*y matrix with columns of unit length?

Tags: algorithm, random, matrix

Is there any specific form or algorithm of generating a random matrix in which all it's columns norm is equal to one?

I'll do an implementation of the algorithm in c/obj-c. However just the general idea of how to do it would suit me!

Comment: You could normalize the columns after you randomly generate the values.

Comment: @mbeckish, so, there is a way of normalizing each column in order that it's norm is equal to 1? How would one do that?

Comment: [Have a look at this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7977/how-to-generate-uniformly-distributed-points-on-the-surface-of-the-3-d-unit-sphe). In summary, if you generate a random unit vector by drawing each coordinate from the standard gaussian distribution then normalize (divide it by its length), you get a uniform distribution of directions. Just do this for each column.

Comment: See the first part of this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10178470/56778

Comment: Divide each value in the column by the vector length of the column.

Comment: Are you after Integer values only?

Comment: @glh, nope. I want random numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made it.

In that answer two things are wrong:

- the number generation, which are not pseudo random numbers from an uniform distribution;
- the normalisation is not being done right; the division should be made by the vector length and not by the number of elements in the vector.

This is the correct code. By the way, I've used a snippet code from [this](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/c_src/ziggurat/ziggurat.html) library, that implements the [Ziggurat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziggurat) algorithm.

```
 + (NSMutableArray *) generateNormalPseudoRandomNumbers:(NSInteger)n {

  NSMutableArray *randomNumberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:n];

  unsigned long int seed;

  for (NSInteger j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
  {
    if ( ( j % 2 ) == 0 )
    {
      seed = 123456789;
    }
    else
    {
      seed = 987654321;
    }

    for (NSInteger i = 1; i <= 10; i++ )
    {
      float value = [Utils r4_uni:&seed];
      [randomNumberArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:value]];
    }
  }

  return randomNumberArray;
}

 + (double) computeVectorNorm:(NSMutableArray *) matrix {
  NSInteger x = [matrix count];
  double norm = 0;

  for(NSInteger i=0; i<x;i++){
      norm += pow([[matrix objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue], 2.0f);
  }
  norm = sqrt(norm);

  return norm;
}
 + (NSMutableArray *) normalizeRandomNumberArray:(NSMutableArray *) randomNumberArray {
  double norm = [self computeVectorNorm:randomNumberArray];

  for(NSInteger i=0; i< [randomNumberArray count]; i++) {
    NSNumber *normalizedNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:([[randomNumberArray objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue] / norm)];
    [randomNumberArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:normalizedNumber];
  }

  return randomNumberArray;
}

+ (double *) generateAMatrix:(NSInteger)k d:(NSInteger)d {

  double *matrix = (double *) malloc(k * d * sizeof(double)); 
  for(NSInteger i=0; i < k; i++) {
    NSMutableArray *column = [self normalizeRandomNumberArray:[self generateNormalPseudoRandomNumbers:d]];
    for(NSInteger j=0; j<d; j++) {
      matrix[i*d+j] = [[column objectAtIndex:j] doubleValue];
    }
  }

  return matrix;
}
```